# How to collect multiple lists to one list with java-streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I collect multiple `List` values into one list, using `java-streams`?

```
List<MyListService> services;

services.stream().XXX.collect(Collectors.toList());


interface MyListService {
   List<MyObject> getObjects();
}
```

As I have full control over the interface: or should I change the method to return an **Array** instead of a List?

Comment: That depends on what `MyListService` is and how you obtain List[s] from instances of it.

Comment: What exactly is `MyListService`? Can you share its public methods please? How should the result look?

Comment: The service may contain *any* method that returns a list of objects

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can collect the Lists contained in the `MyListService` instances with `flatMap` :

```
List<MyObject> list = services.stream()
                              .flatMap(s -> s.getObjects().stream())
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Great that works, if it's the preferred way.

Comment: @membersound That's what `flatMap` exists for.

Comment: Omg thanks this saved me from creating extra lists and moving them all 1 by 1 with a For Each